# JAWS screen reader and using Hash Tag Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jaws-screen-reader

I have a aspx page which includes links to the same page as below:

```html
<h1>start </h1>
some html code
<ul>
        <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
    </ul>
<h3 id="one">one </h3>some content

<h3 id="two">two </h3>some content
```

I am using JAWS 16 and noticed when I clicked on the link one or two the page is scrolled to the selected link but the JAWS is reading the page from top of it (page title) instead of starting from related h3 tag.

How can I fixed the issue? any idea.

Thanks!